# Is nested list not suitable for manipulating single element in vector?

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply

I have a following code:

```
for(i in 1:length(hh_temp)){
  hh_temp_save = hh_temp[[i]]
  for(j in 4:nrow(hh_temp_save)){
    hh_temp_save$max_min_sum_5days[j] = ifelse(sum(hh_temp_save$max_min_sum[(j-4):j])>2,1,0)
    hh_temp[[i]] = hh_temp_save
 }
}
```

where `hh_temp` is a list with length(hh_temp) = 12, each element in `hh_temp` is a dataframe.

I tried to convert the for-loop into nested apply but I found that

```
lapply(hh_temp,\(x){
  x = lapply(32:nrow(x),\(y){
             x$max_min_sum_5days[y] = ifelse(sum(x$max_min_sum[(y-4):y])>2,1,0)
             x
             })
  return(x)
               })
```

I can only return the manipulated vector instead of the whole dataset. Is there any way to return the whole dataset? Does it mean nested `lapply` is not suitable for manipulating single element in a vector?

I am sorry that I cannot provide the detail of dataset, some descriptive statistics can be provided:

```
> str(hh_temp)
List of 12
 $ : tibble [3,684 × 36] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ max_min_sum                                      : num [1:3684] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ max_min_sum_5days                                : num [1:3684] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : tibble [3,684 × 36] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ max_min_sum                                      : num [1:3684] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ max_min_sum_5days                                : num [1:3684] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

#repeated for 12 times
#max_min_sum is a binary variable
```

Sample data:

```
df = data.frame(a = as.factor(c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1)),
                b = rep(NA,18))

sample_list = list(df,df,df,df,df,df)
```

My expected outcome is to calculate the cumulative sum of the 5 consecutive elements in a and then if the consecutive sum is greater than 2, the corresponding element in b will be recoded as 1, otherwise 0.

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NA |
| 1 | NA |
| 1 | NA |
| 1 | NA |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |

In the 5th element in a,
since there are 4 `1s` and 1 `0`, therefore, the consecutive sum is greater than 2, the corresponding element in b will be recoded as `1`.

Comment: I can't debug your code without any sample data to test on. Perhaps you could create a small sample data frame for illustrative purposes? It certainly doesn't need to be 3684x36 and real data, I would think 8x2 of fake data would be plenty to demonstrate the problem. And it would also help a lot if you would describe in words what the operation you are doing is.

Comment: The sample data is added. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: In general, `lapply` returns a `list`, and you want to edit part of a vector. So `lapply` seems like not the best choice for your inner loop, though it could be made to work. It seems like you are calculating some sort of rolling or sliding sum, and there are plenty of packages and functions designed to do that. But without sample input, desired output, or a description of the operation, I don't think I can be of more help.

Comment: Lastly, I'd say that the outer `lapply` is simple. Whatever your solution is for one data frame, `lapply(sample_list, that_solution)` should work. So instead focus your question on the inner operation. You've now got sample input. Describe what you want to do, show the desired result, and maybe we can help you do it.

Comment: Why does your sample data use the `factor` class? If you want to sum things up, that doesn't make much sense...

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I used factor class is for my own analysis. Also, the expected outcome is updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My expected outcome is to calculate the cumulative sum of the 5 consecutive elements in a and then if the consecutive sum is greater than 2, the corresponding element in b will be recoded as 1, otherwise 0.

If `a` is a factor variable, we need to run `as.numeric(as.character(a))` beforehand to coerce `a` to numeric. We can use `rollsum()` from `{zoo}` for the rolling sum calulation.

A solution using `lapply()` applied to slightly modified sample data.

**Code**

```r
# sample_list = 
  lapply(sample_list, 
         \(x) { x$b = ifelse(
           zoo::rollsum(as.numeric(as.character(x$a)), 
                        k = 5, fill = NA, align = "right") > 2L, 1L, 0L)
         x})
```

Or in a more compact way as suggested by @G. Grothendieck like

```r
lapply(sample_list, transform, 
       b = +(zoo::rollsumr(as.numeric(as.character(a)), k = 5L, fill = NA) > 2L))
```

**Result**

```r
#> [[1]]
#>    a  b
#> 1  1 NA
#> 2  1 NA
#> 3  1 NA
#> 4  1 NA
#> 5  0  1
#> 6  0  1
#> 7  0  0
#> 8  0  0
#> 9  1  0
#> 10 1  0
#> 11 1  1
#> 12 1  1
#> 13 1  1
#> 14 0  1
#> 15 0  1
#> 16 1  1
#> 17 0  0
#> 18 1  0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    a  b
#> 1  1 NA
#> 2  2 NA
#> 3  3 NA
#> 4  4 NA
#> 5  5  1
#> 6  6  1
#> 7  7  1
#> 8  8  1
#> 9  1  1
#> 10 1  1
#> 11 1  1
#> 12 1  1
#> 13 1  1
#> 14 1  1
#> 15 1  1
#> 16 1  1
#> 17 1  1
#> 18 1  1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>    a  b
#> 1  1 NA
#> 2  1 NA
#> 3  1 NA
#> 4  1 NA
#> 5  0  1
#> 6  0  1
#> 7  0  0
#> 8  0  0
#> 9  1  0
#> 10 1  0
#> 11 1  1
#> 12 1  1
#> 13 1  1
#> 14 0  1
#> 15 0  1
#> 16 1  1
#> 17 0  0
#> 18 1  0
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>    a  b
#> 1  1 NA
#> 2  1 NA
#> 3  1 NA
#> 4  1 NA
#> 5  0  1
#> 6  0  1
#> 7  0  0
#> 8  0  0
#> 9  1  0
#> 10 1  0
#> 11 1  1
#> 12 1  1
#> 13 1  1
#> 14 0  1
#> 15 0  1
#> 16 1  1
#> 17 0  0
#> 18 1  0
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>    a  b
#> 1  1 NA
#> 2  1 NA
#> 3  1 NA
#> 4  1 NA
#> 5  0  1
#> 6  0  1
#> 7  0  0
#> 8  0  0
#> 9  1  0
#> 10 1  0
#> 11 1  1
#> 12 1  1
#> 13 1  1
#> 14 0  1
#> 15 0  1
#> 16 1  1
#> 17 0  0
#> 18 1  0
#> 
#> [[6]]
#>    a  b
#> 1  1 NA
#> 2  1 NA
#> 3  1 NA
#> 4  1 NA
#> 5  0  1
#> 6  0  1
#> 7  0  0
#> 8  0  0
#> 9  1  0
#> 10 1  0
#> 11 1  1
#> 12 1  1
#> 13 1  1
#> 14 0  1
#> 15 0  1
#> 16 1  1
#> 17 0  0
#> 18 1  0
```

**Modified Data**

```r
df = data.frame(a = as.factor(c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1)),
                b = rep(NA,18))
df2 = data.frame(a = as.factor(c(1:8, rep(1, 5), rep(1,5))), 
                 b = rep(NA,18))
sample_list = list(df,df2,df,df,df,df)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Edit**

If your data is rather small and you do not want to rely on an external package like `{zoo}`, you might consider to write your own
rolling sum function. Very basic example:

```r
basic_rollsum = \(x, k) {
  # stopifnot(is.numeric(x), is.integer(k))
  res = rep(NA, length(x))
  for (i in seq_along(x)) 
    # adjust indexing if needed 
    # look at na.rm-argument of sum
    if (i > k) res[i] = sum( x[(i-k+1L):(i)] )
  res
}
lapply(sample_list, 
       \(x) { x$b = ifelse(
         basic_rollsum(as.numeric(as.character(x$a)), k = 5L) > 2L, 1L, 0L)
       x})
```

Comment: This can be written compactly as  
`library(zoo); lapply(sample_list, transform, b = +(rollsumr(strtoi(a), 5, NA) > 2L))`